# ggplot2 - How to sort stackedbars based on categorical and numerical variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, stacked-chart

I am trying to create a stacked barplot, using ggplot2, sorting by multiple criteria. Here is the dataframe I am working with -

```
my_df<-data.frame('sub_n'=c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3),rep(3,3),rep(4,3),rep(5,3)),'total'=c(1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3),'choice'=c(rep(c('a','b','c'),5)))
```

What I ultimately wish to have, is a stacked barplot, sorted based on the quantities of 'choice' present. Specifically, I want to create a sideways, stacked plot, with the bars at the top having the highest 'total' values of choice==b, followed by the bars that have the highest 'total' values of choice==c, followed by the bars that have the highest 'total' values of choice==a.

Here is what I have tried to do so far -

```
require(dplyr)
require(forcats)
my_df<-my_df %>% 
  arrange(choice, desc(total)) %>% 
  mutate(choice=fct_reorder(choice,total))
order_1<-unique(my_df$sub_n)
my_df$sub_n<-factor(my_df$sub_n, levels=order_1)
my_df <- my_df[order(my_df$sub_n),]
ggplot(data=my_df, aes(x=sub_n, y=total, fill=choice))+
  geom_bar(position="stack",stat="identity")+
  coord_flip()
```

[image: Plot]

I am not even sure if I am explaining this correctly, please let me know if there is something else I can include to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

This one is surprisingly tricky in my opinion. Here's an approach that uses `arrange` to order by the conditions and then `row_number()` to set the rank. Thanks to @akrun in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48018547/13095326) for the inspiration.

We can use `pivot_wider` to make it easy to order by each of the variables.

Once we've got the ranks set up, we can join back onto the data and re-order the factors with `fct_reorder` as you did in your attempt.

If you want to re-order the place in the bar the factors are, you can use `fct_relevel`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(forcats)
library(ggplot)
my_df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "choice", values_from = "total") %>%
  arrange(desc(b),desc(c),desc(a)) %>% 
  mutate(rank = row_number()) %>%
  right_join(my_df,by = "sub_n") %>%
  mutate(sub_n = fct_reorder(as.factor(sub_n), desc(rank)),
         choice = fct_relevel(choice,c("a","c","b"))) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=sub_n, y=total, fill=choice))+
  geom_bar(position="stack",stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(b = "#00BA38", c = "#619CFF", a = "#F8766D")) + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. But is there a way to visualize it so that b (green) comes first in each subject, followed by c, followed by a? This is a sample data set from a much larger set, and I'm trying to essentially visualize patterns, if there are individuals more prone to choosing one option compared to another.